# Android Dagger2: How to use dependency injection in non Activity/Fragment class

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I m able to use dependency injection easily using **AndroidInjection.inject(this)** or **AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)**  in onCreate(). I want to use dependency inject in a java class which is neither an activity nor a fragment

Here is my AppComponect class

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        ApplicationModule.class,
        ActivityBuilder.class})

public interface ApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {
void inject(AppController appController);
void inject(APIHelper apiHelper);

@Override
void inject(DaggerApplication daggerApplication);

@Component.Builder
interface Builder{
    @BindsInstance
    Builder application(Application application);
    ApplicationComponent build();
}
```

**Non-Activity/Fragment class**

```
public class APIHandler {

    /**
     * Activity reference object
     */
    private Activity mActivity;
    /**
     * Debug TAG
     */
    private String TAG = APIHandler.class.getSimpleName();
 @Inject
    DataManager dataManager;

    /**
     * Public Constructor for this class
     *
     * @param mActivity
     * @param webAPIResponseListener
     */
    public APIHandler(Activity mActivity, WebAPIResponseListener webAPIResponseListener) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mResponseListener = webAPIResponseListener;
        postAPICall();
    }
//API call
    public void postAPICall() {
//doing something
if(dataManager != null){
dataManager.setName();
}
}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use **AndroidInjection** with (Activity, Fragment, Service, ContentProvider and BroadcastReceiver) as [the documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.13/dagger/android/AndroidInjection.html) says.

If you want to use dependency inject in a java class which is neither an activity nor any of the above classes, so you have to create an interface like for example

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {

   AuthComponent plusAuthComponent();

   void inject(AnyClassType any);
   void inject(AnotherType another);
   void inject(Again again);

}
```

And I think [this](https://github.com/larkintuckerllc/daggerscope/tree/master) will help you. 
Another amazing tutorial on Youtube [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qwk7ESmaCq0&list=PLuR1PJnGR-Ih-HXnGSpnqjdhdvqcwhfFU)

Comment: I have edited the code above.Please let me know if I have missed something